# What does Statement.executeQuery() return for a SELECT statement

Tags: java, jdbc, resultset

What does `executeQuery(String sql)` return when there are no entries in the table?

And I want to know that `executeQuery` method return type is `ResultSet`.

Then after execution of query, what `executeQuery` return to `ResultSet` reference variable. Will it return `null` or something else?

Comment: why don't you read the documentation

Answer (score 4):

As stated in the [JavaDoc for `Statement.executeQuery()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#executeQuery%28java.lang.String%29):

> **Returns:** a ResultSet object that contains the data produced by the given query; never null

In other words, for an empty table (or a query not matching any rows) `resultSet.next()` will evaluate to `false` and not cause an NPE.

Cheers,

Comment: but if query not matching any rows.what actually resultset contains?

Comment: If the query doesn't match any rows, the `ResultSet` will be empty. You can't `.next()` it and expect to eg. call `.getString()`on it.

Answer (score 0):

ResultSet rs = Statement.executeQuery(select statement)

Statement.executeQuery() - Executes the given SQL statement, which **returns a single ResultSet object**.

This ResultSet object contains data (which it gets from the Database)

Now, when we use getXXX(); methods to read the content, it checks whether the asked data is present in ResultSet object or not, if yes, it returns the data from the resultSet object else

Returns:
    the column value; if the value is SQL NULL, then value returned is 0

if the columnLabel is not valid; if a database access error occurs or this method is called on a closed result set